# C++ parse input file and copy data to an output file

Tags: c++, function, file-io

I have a file called input.txt which contains a sequence of nested objects, where each object is delimited by { and }. Attributes within the objects contain a name followed by at least one white space followed by a set of parameters delimited by ( and ). A comma separates multiple parameters see below

input.txt

```
{
colour (3)
position (3,4)
size (2)
{
position (13,4)
size (2)
colour (5)
}
...
```

how do I create a function to parse the input file and copy the data to an output file?

so far i have tried

```
parser(char filenamein[], char filenameout[])
{
ifstream fin(filenamein);
if(fin.is_open())
{
    ofstream fout(filenameout);

    char c;
    while (fin.good())
    {
        fin.get(c);
        fout << c;
    }

    fout.close();
    fin.close();

    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: short answer: design and implement an automata.

Comment: What's the format of your output file? Is it exactly the same with the input file?

Comment: Hang on.  Are you just trying to *copy* the file?  Do you need to interpret it in any way?

Comment: trying to copy the data to an output file, then locate the object with the largest size and print out to the console window the level within the object hierarchy. Assuming that that the initial outer most object level is 1,  the print out should be something like "largest object is of size(size value) and is located at level (level value)"

Comment: @Marc: Ok, well that's quite a different question.  Please edit your question so that it says what you *really* want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the code to copy one file to another, following code can serve. Of course there is more than one way to achieve this, as you can see.

```
int copy_file()
{
    ifstream input("c:\\input.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

    if(!input.good())
    {
        // error opening input file
        return -1;
    }

    ofstream output("c:\\output.txt", std::ios::trunc|std::ios::binary);

    if(!output.good())
    {
        // error opening output file
        return -2;
    }

    output << input.rdbuf();

    if(!output.good())
    {
        // writing to file failed
        return -3;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) library.